# AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED for non developer users

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed an application that works with facebook. For me as a developer the application works great, but when tried to test it on friends phone I got error when trying to sync with facebook and I got the error : AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED.
Did I get it because my app is still not authorized with facebook and I did't finished the Review Submission Form?
If I will add my friends as testers it will work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app setting and check if it is in sandbox mode.
Switch the sandbox mode off.

Comment: I can do this only after I submit the review form and my app is authorized by facebook. Am I right?

Comment: No that is not necessary.
Just disable the sandbox mode. And you are ok to go